# Why json file doesn't open in my program?

Tags: python, json

I have a school schedule in my program, and when I use

```
import json


if choice == "Schedule":
    with open("Schedule.json", "r") as schedule_file:
        schedule_output = json.load(schedule_file)
        schedule_choice = input('\nDo you want to exit or change the schedule?\n')
```

The problem comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "practice.py", line 92, in <module>
    schedule_output = json.load(schedule_file)
  File "C:\Users\Samwise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Samwise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Samwise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Samwise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried to change the encoding, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Try using `json.loads()` instead of `json.load()`

Comment: Looks like file content is not valid json. Can you check it?

Comment: I've tried to use loads instead of load, and there is another problem:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 92, in <module>
    schedule_output = json.loads(schedule_file)
  File "C:\Users\Samwise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper`

Comment: My json file contains only text information, just a schedule of subjects @neverwalkaloner

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] before asking here. Make sure the error message corresponds to running that code (it refers to line 92 here, but there is no such line). As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: it seems your file has incorrect JSON data or maybe it is even empty. So first open it in any text editor and see what you have in this file. You could also add this file to question.